# Excel VBA Not Writing to Summary Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code to copy certain ranges of data from each sheet to a summary sheet.  I have attempted many versions of this (far too many for me to put them all here), but with each one the summary sheet has empty values. I don't understand what is going wrong, and I have no theories.

Here is the version that I wrote myself.  All of the other variations I tried were found on the Internet:

Note: The actual summary sheet is created elsewhere in code.  Also, the reason why I have sheetIndex starting at 6 is because that's the first sheet I want to take data from.

```
Sub PopulateSummary()
Dim nmbrParts As Integer
Dim partIndex As Integer
Dim sheetIndex As Integer
Dim sheetCount As Integer

sheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
for sheetIndex = 6 To sheetCount
    With Sheets(sheetIndex)
        .Activate
        .Range("B2").Select
        Call SelectFirstToLastInColumn
        nmbrParts = Selection.Count
        Sheets("Summary").Activate
        for partIndex = 1 To nmbrParts
            row = partIndex + 1

            Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 1).Value = .Cells(row, 1).Value
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 2).Value = .Cells(row, 2).Value
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 3).Value = .Cells(row, 4).Value
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 3).Value = .Cells(row, 3).Value
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 5).Value = .Cells(row, 6).Value

        Next partIndex
    End With
Next sheetIndex
```

End Sub

EDIT: I figured something out.  Since I'm invoking these macros from another workbook, I changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook, so it counts the right number of sheets.  The problem isn't solved, though.

Comment: Can you run the macro step by step (F8 in the Visual Basic window) and pause on 'nmbrParts = Selection.Count'.  Check that the cells are actually selected and if so, proceed down to '.Cells(row, 1).Value' and determine if that value is the value you want.  Add a watch to display the value in the Watches window.

Answer (score 4):

Break it into pieces and step through the code one line at a time. That will tell you whether you're selecting what you think you're selecting, whether row is what you think it is, etc. Also, pause when the code hits your first Sheets("Summary").Cells... line and use the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) to output the value of your destination cell with

```
?.Cells(row, 1).Value
```

Also, since you've got a With block, you don't really need to activate and select cells (and you shouldn't select most of the time in VBA anyway, as doing stuff in the sheet is slow), and you also don't have to activate Sheets("Summary") since you're referencing it directly. You could do something like:

```
With Sheets(sheetIndex)
    nmbrParts = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="*",searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    for ...
    .
    . 
    .
End With
```

The simpler and shorter the code, the easier it is to test.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I will begin testing right away.

Comment: Um, so I began testing, and I realized that my intial for loop with the sheetIndex = 6 To sheetCount evaluates in such a manner that it skips my loop entirely.  EDIT: ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count returns 1 for some reason.

Comment: So I did what you told me to do.  It outputted the exact value that I wanted it to output.  Still not writing it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out....

I was having some problem with variable names being in the wrong place.  My macro SHOULD look
something like this:

```
Sub PopulateSummary()
Dim nmbrParts As Integer
Dim partIndex As Integer
Dim sheetIndex As Integer
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For sheetIndex = 6 To sheetCount
    With Sheets(sheetIndex)
        .Activate
        .Range("B2").Select
        nmbrParts = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="*", searchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
        For partIndex = 1 To nmbrParts
             destRow = partIndex + 1
             Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 1).Value = .Cells(destRow, 1).Value
             Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 2).Value = .Cells(destRow, 2).Value
             Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 3).Value = .Cells(destRow, 4).Value
             Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 4).Value = .Cells(destRow, 3).Value
             Sheets("Summary").Cells(row, 5).Value = .Cells(destRow, 6).Value
             row = row + 1
        Next partIndex
    End With
Next sheetIndex
End Sub
```

The difference is that I used a different name to refer to rows on the sheets that I was taking from.  So, I would be able to keep the numbers separate.  I also found an error that I had mentioned in my Edit where I had to change ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook so the sheet count could be correct.

Thanks to redOctober13 for the testing advice.  You've taught me the importance of using the debugger.